# How to create a banner in ECLIPSE

Tags: eclipse, mobile, ads

i want to start CPA mobile.
I create a banner with photoshop and I have the Url to promote.
Please how can I add a banner with the URL.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about adding admob banner then you can follow admob documentation.
There is sample code to add banners